# Как с помощью EventBus передать объект в активити и в фрагмент?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity, eventbus

У меня есть 2 активити - MainActivity и BaseActivity, у BaseActivity есть фрагмент InfoFragment.

Есть объект Info - содержащий около 20 полей. В MainActivity. Данные поля используются для заполнения текстом TextView в BaseActivity и InfoFragment.
как с помощью EventBus передать Info из MainActivity в BaseActivity и InfoFragment.

PS.: использую способы с примеров, ставлю регистраторы в onCreate и в onAttach, отправляю событие из Main в Base, а затем из Base во фрагмент, однако в итоге получаю null.

Код события (которое передаю):

```
public class AAinfo {

private Info info;  

public AAinfo(Info info) {  
    this.info = info; 
}

public Info getInfo() {
    return info;
}
}
```

Передаю так:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new AAinfo (info));
```

В подписчике определяю метод:

```
@Subscribe
public void onEvent (AAinfo event) {
this.info = event.getInfo();
}
```

Comment: может проще использовать штатные средства типа extras у intent ?

Comment: Читал статьи о том, что производительней использовать данную библиотеку.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался что к чему, по своей глупости упустил то, что передаю событие в ещё неработающую активити. Если кому интересно решение, то в данной ситуации необходимо использовать postSticky(Object object) - липкое событие, которое существует и после его создания